# How can I locate a UI element in VB6 code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6

I have no experience with VB, but I have looked around a decent amount and cannot figure this out.

I am currently recreating a VB6 application to a VB.net application. There are a bunch of elements that are hidden until certain options are chosen. Obviously, not having the element created on the form gives me this error:

[image]

Looking at the VB6 environment, I find the **mDNP** variable in the drop down menu on the right, but it does not tell me where it is located, or what type of UI element it is. It says *Menu* next to it, but I have gone through all of the menus and cannot find it anywhere.

[image]

Comment: an object being created and being visible are 2 different things.  the error you are seeing may simply mean it does not exist in this context.  If the code is in a class or module it may not have access to a menuitem on a form.  Are you manually recoding this or working with the output from a converter?  In VB6 a `menu` would likely refer to one of the drop downs - right click on the form and select `Menu Editor` to see those for that form (including "hidden" ones for popups).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The error appears in VB.NET, because I have copy/pasted the VB6 code. The second image shows the VB6 project. I will check the Menu Editor now.

Comment: That menu editor was what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: yes, i understand, but you also said you were trying to find mDNP in the VB6 project and could not find it - presumably so you can see what it is to add it to VB.NET project.

Comment: Yup, if you would like to answer the question with the 'Menu Editor' information I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue of hidden elements is not the cause of the error; even if not visible, they must exist.  More likely, you havent yet (re)created that VB6 object in the new NET project code (especially if you cannot find it in VB6).

Menus were odd in VB6 and used a special editor rather than just being a component or control you added. `mDNP` likely relates to a drop down menu list/window.  To find all these creatures in VB6:

- Open the form designer
- Right Click
- Select `Menu Editor`

There is also a toolbar button, but it may missing as a result of customization:

[image]

This will show all the menu elements for this form including ones which might be set to invisible to be later invoked as `PopUps` or context menus in today's lingo.  There is no indicator that a form has a menu (like the form tray components in .NET) other than opening the Menu Editor.